# optimal way to read chunks of a file while searching for a delimiter in c++?

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

I want to split a file into several new files depending on the number of new line characters there are. Currently, I only read byte by byte looking for the newline character at each read. My issue is that I feel that my method is too slow. I do not want to call any functions. Is there a rule that I should follow in regards to how big of a chunk at each read call I should be doing?

I was thinking that maybe I should read in chunks and then iterate over each chunk looking for the newline character and setting the cursor to just after that newline character. Though, I am not sure as to how this may save me time in terms of runtime. Is reading byte by byte using the read call gonna take longer than me iterating over each chunk?

Also, are there differences between IO libraries? I've heard of how IO streams work, but don't see how that may be better than the IO system call libraries from C.

Comment: Measure first. Always measure first.

Comment: It would be much faster not to limit the chunks by number of lines, but by max size, and by splitting the chunks on the last line therein. As it is, _buffered reading_ should already be faster too, and then scanning in the buffer.

Comment: @PasserBy How am I to tell the position of the newline character at each read call then? Do you mean measure the size of the file I am processing to come up with a decent rate so as to not perform to many overreads?

Comment: @JoopEggen This sounds like a great method, but the issue is that it is a requirement to split based on the newline characters and not on the last character in each chunk.

Comment: The file I/O is the limiting factor, not your code.  `fstream` is buffered anyway, so it should make very little difference whether you read it in chunks or not.  The benefit to reading one character at a time is that it's simple.  A simple way to handle it then is that when you find a newline _and_ you've reached your threshold for a split, then call `tellg()` on your stream and push that onto a vector, then reset your count.  When you reach the end of the file, push one more `tellg` result onto the vector, and now you have a list of chunk end positions.

Comment: I mean _"I feel that my method is too slow"_ is not how you do this. You get proof that it is too slow, by measuring.

Comment: If you're actually trying to split the file into multiple files, then instead of storing positions, just store the data as you read it.  This avoids reading the file a second time.  When you reach the end of a line and hit the chunk size limit or end of file, then write that data out to its file, clear the buffer and continue.

Comment: If you want to read a certain number of whole lines, I would consider using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read one line at a time.

Comment: @DataInTheStone I mean instead of reading every line end and count the lines, you read the last 128 bytes part(s) of the the chunk at max chunk size. and search backwards to the line end of the last line in the chunk. That can be much faster splitting. Though the number of lines in the chunk will be unclear.